# How to extract a string from a file name?

Tags: shell-script, filenames

I'm trying to read a part of a file name to make it in an `if .. else` statement

for example :
**file name :**  `foo_bar_test1_example.stat`

I want to do a test; if the word : `example` exists in the file name , then there are some scripts to execute.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I'm new with shell scripting ..is there something wrong with the question ? why Its down voted ? :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `bash` you can do as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#let's look for an a in our handful of files
string="a"
for file in aa ab bb cc dd ad ; do
  #note the placement of the asterisks and the quotes
  #do not swap file and string!
  if [[ "$file" == *"$string"* ]] ; then
     echo "$string in $file"
  else
     echo "no match for $file"
  fi
done
```

EDIT: simplification with `bash`'s regex matching, as suggested by @JeffSchaller:

```
if [[ "$file" =~ $string ]] ; then
```

Comment: also with bash, you can use regular expression matching inside [[, such as: `if [[ "$file" =~ example ]]; then echo found; else echo not found; fi`

Comment: @JeffSchaller pretty good point, I had forgotten about this option. updated

Comment: Note that they're not specific to `bash`. The `[[ string == pattern ]]` comes from `ksh` and is available in bash, ksh and zsh, `[[ string =~ regexp ]]` comes from `bash` and is available in bash, ksh93 and zsh. However note that with bash 3.1 and below and zsh `$string` would be considered as a regexp.

Answer (score 5):

`case` is the construct for that in shells of the Bourne family (Bourne, Almquist, ksh, bash, zsh, yash...):

```
case $file in
  *example*) do-something-for-example "$file";;
  *) do-something-else-if-not "$file";;
esac
```

In shells of the `csh` family (csh, tcsh):

```
switch ($file:q)
  case *example*:
    do-something-with $file:q
    breaksw

  default:
    do-something-else-with $file:q
    breaksw
endsw
```

In the `fish` shell:

```
switch $file
  case '*example*'
    do-something-with $file
  case '*'
    do-something-else-with $file
end
```

With `rc` or `aganga`:

```
switch ($file) {
  case *example*
    do-something-with $file

  case *
    do-something-else-with $file
}
```

With `es`:

```
if {~ $file *example*} {
  do-something-with $file
} {
  do-something-else-with $file
}
```